# print cvs with decription column and multiple rows

Tags: gnuplot

i've got a csv file with this content (Row = Title + 10 Values, Row = Line in chart)
column-count is known (but would be great if only the Title is needed and value count is open (but same for all rows)), row count is open

```
Test1;0,051;0,040;0,051;0,052;0,051;0,049;0,051;0,052;0,059;0,044
Test2;0,016;0,016;0,016;0,019;0,021;0,021;0,021;0,021;0,022;0,022
Test3;0,216;0,200;0,210;0,205;0,205;0,205;0,203;0,206;0,205;0,204
```

result in LibreOffice

[image]

now i want to print it with gnuplot

i tried it with

```
set xrange [1:10]
set yrange [0:2]
plot for [row=0:*] 'test.csv' matrix every :::row::row with lines
```

but that only gives me several error messages

```
"gnuplot.txt" line 7: warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values
"gnuplot.txt" line 7: warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values
"gnuplot.txt" line 7: warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values
"gnuplot.txt" line 7: warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values
```

would be nice if someone can give me a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, gnuplot doesn't like data in rows and doesn't have a transpose function. I guess there is a way to plot rows with `matrix` as you tried, but currently I don't see a direct way to include the rowheaders as key entry.

So, either you use an external tool and transpose your data or you use the cumbersome gnuplot-transpose-attempt below and then plot columns. At least, this should work for Linux as well as for Windows without the installation of extra tools.

Your decimal sign is `,`. Since my standard decimalsign is `.`, I had to set:

```
set decimalsign locale 'french'   # or 'german' might also work
```

**Data:** `test.csv`

```
Test1;0,051;0,040;0,051;0,052;0,051;0,049;0,051;0,052;0,059;0,044
Test2;0,016;0,016;0,016;0,019;0,021;0,021;0,021;0,021;0,022;0,022
Test3;0,216;0,200;0,210;0,205;0,205;0,205;0,203;0,206;0,205;0,204
```

**Code:**

```
### plot row data with rowheader as key entry
reset session

myFile = 'test.csv'

set datafile separator ';'
set decimalsign locale 'french'   # or 'german' should also work

# transpose data
stats myFile u 0 nooutput
set table $Dummy
    set print $DataTransposed
        do for [i=1:STATS_columns] {
            LINE = ''
            do for [j=0:STATS_records-1] {
                plot myFile u (a=stringcolumn(i)) every ::j::j with table
                LINE = LINE.sprintf('%s', j < STATS_records-1 ? a.";" : a)
            }
        print LINE
        }
    set print
unset table
undefine $Dummy

plot for [i=1:STATS_records] $DataTransposed u ($0+1):i w l ti columnheader
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: console output is only **decimal_sign in locale is ,** and gnuplot window closes immediately without any other message, im using "gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8" under windows from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.2.8/gp528-win64-mingw.exe/download

Comment: do you have a "permanent" console started by `wgnuplot.exe`. How do you load the script? In console: `load "myScript.gp"` ?

Comment: what is your gnuplot working directory? In gnuplot console type `pwd`. What is the location of your script and your file `test.csv`?

Comment: ok works when starting wgnuplot.exe plus load 'gnuplot.txt' in the gnupolt console or **gnuplot.exe gnuplot.txt -persist** - thank you very much for your help